# Flask and Pandas

Tags: flask

I am trying to show a pandas dataframe in flask and I am using the to_html() function to do so. However, it seems that the to_html() overwrites my html template. Flask shows the dataframe but not within the home.html template. I can't quite figure out how to get the dataframe to appear in the home.html template. How can I format the dataframe within the home.html template?

```
@app.route('/')
def index():

df_holdings=pd.read_csv('Holdings.csv')
df_holdings=df_holdings[['Sector','Security','Position','% Wgt','Market 
Value','Closing Price']]
return df_holdings.to_html()
return render_template('home.html')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two return statements, one returning the html from the DataFrame and one returning the template. The call `to_html` is not overwriting your `home` template, but returning the `html` before it's even reaching `render_template`.

You need to pass your `html` from your DataFrame into `render_template` and then render the results

**Python**

```
@app.route('/')
def index():    
    df_holdings=pd.read_csv('Holdings.csv')
    df_holdings=df_holdings[['Sector','Security','Position','% Wgt','Market 
    Value','Closing Price']]
    return render_template('home.html', html=df_holdings.to_html())
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>
        {{ html|safe }}
    </body>
</html>
```